# VSS alternatives for non coders to share excel files etc?

Tags: version-control, open-source, visual-sourcesafe, file-sharing

I need to find an open source alternative to VSS where people will share things like Excel sheets,PPT etc. It will be used by extremely non technical people on windows, so I have ruled out SVN,CVS,GIT etc. I need simple checkin and checkout system for stuff like Excel sheets. Can people suggest something from open source??

Comment: I want a system where people edit different sheets on the Excel file at the same time and check in the evening and everything gets synchronised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the vss locking facility where if one person has a file checked out then other people are prevented from editing the file?

If you do then be aware that nearly all source control systems like cvs, svn, git etc. allow multiple users to edit the files, and merge the changes later, which will be a problem for Excel sheets

If you don't then simple file sharing systems like [google docs](http://docs.google.com) or [dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) might suit.

**Update**

The [Share Workbook option in the Tools menu](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002916_Sharing_Your_Workbook.html) suggests a way of multiple users editing the same document

Comment: i think this works for me..and people around..

Comment: Share Workbook option in the Tools menu is fine for simple people

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple [Sharepoint Document Library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011412871033.aspx)?

The advantage that I see is that all the checking - checkout process is not so complicated.

Comment: Isn't this user profile exactly what sharepoint is for?

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is a graphical SVN client that works from the windows explorer. It adds check in/out to the context menu of files, so I thing people can use it with minor training.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/

Comment: has to get simpler..You can say it has to be done by dumb people..

Comment: I don't know if it gets simpler than tortoisesvn?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Microsoft's Groove? That works pretty well ...